# My "IF " and Elif Statements are not Working

Tags: python

So if and elif statements are not working

```
def weight_converter():
  print("Welcome to Weight Converter")
  operation = int(input(" 1. Gram to Pound \n 2. Pound into Gram"))
   if operation == " 1":
     gram_one = int(input("Grams needed to convert to pound: "))
     print("You have", gram_one * 453.57,"pounds")
   elif operation == " 2":
     pound_one = int(inpu())
  
weight_converter()
```

So I am expecting for the if statement to run but then the gram_one input does not show up. Please help me to fix that.

Comment: ``operation=int(whatever)`` means that operation is an integer. So it can't be anything like the string `" 1"`. No way `'operation  == " 1"` nor `"operation == " 2"` could ever be true

Comment: Try `if operation == 1` instead of `if operation == " 1"`. Also, what is `inpu()`? That looks like a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Your code snippet should be like one of the below code snippets:

```py
def weight_converter():
  print("Welcome to Weight Converter")
  operation = int(input(" 1. Gram to Pound \n 2. Pound into Gram"))
   if operation == 1:
     gram_one = int(input("Grams needed to convert to pound: "))
     print("You have", gram_one * 453.57,"pounds")
   elif operation == 2:
     pound_one = int(input())
  
weight_converter()
```

or

```py
def weight_converter():
  print("Welcome to Weight Converter")
  operation = input(" 1. Gram to Pound \n 2. Pound into Gram")
   if operation == "1":
     gram_one = int(input("Grams needed to convert to pound: "))
     print("You have", gram_one * 453.57,"pounds")
   elif operation == "2":
     pound_one = int(inpu())
  
weight_converter()
```

In both above code snippets by entering just *1* or *2* by the keyboard if/elif statements works ok.

Answer (score 1):

I think you were on the right track, just a few things that needed to be tweaked:

1. It appears that there was an indentation issue you had, indenting it correctly fixes it.
2. There was a typo in the `elif` block so I just made a tweak to fix that.
3. Because you are using integers for your input, changing it to 2 rather than " 2" fixes that.
4. Added an else block just in case the input is anything but 1 or 2.

Hope this helps put you in the right direction you're expecting.

```
def weight_converter():
  print("Welcome to Weight Converter")
  operation = int(input(" 1. Gram to Pound \n 2. Pound into Gram"))
  if operation == 1:
    gram_one = int(input("Grams needed to convert to pound: "))
    print("You have", gram_one * 453.57,"pounds")
  elif operation == 2:
    pound_one = int(input())
  else:
      print("An error as occurred..")

weight_converter()
```

Comment: Thanks @calimaru1 I actually found that out before I saw your text but I completely agree that I have to change the two into a int.